Did L. Ron Hubbard write about a planet called Trantor?
In an article about the '80s video game Trantor: The Last Stormtrooper, the author, Nick Bruty, says he got the name "Trantor" from "a planet in an L. Ron Hubbard book."
Trantor is a planet in Isaac Asimov's Foundation trilogy, and he used the name in at least one other work. Every search I've done around the name includes Asimov, but I can't find any evidence that Hubbard ever used the name. That might be simply because Asimov's series is so well-known (and Trantor featured a lot there), or it might be that Bruty was misremembering - Hubbard and Asimov's careers overlapped, they might even have had stories published in the same volume at some point.
Did Hubbard ever use the name Trantor for a planet, or for anything else?

I don't see any mention of Hubbard in lists of authors who wrote in the Foundation Universe. Sounds like a confusion, but hard to prove a negative.

In the same interview Nick Bruty said he was reading a lot of sci-fi and does name Asimov, perhaps he just got the names of the authors confused?

@TitaniusAnglesmith I would have thought that would make it part of the Foundation Universe, though I suppose he could have used it without authorization from the Asimov publishers.

@TitaniusAnglesmith I withdraw my objections - my mental map of the periods the two writers were active had Asimov active earlier and Hubbard after, but in reality they overlapped almost exactly it seems.

According to ancestry.co.uk, Trantor is also a surname - not very common, but known in the US. So it's possible they both encountered the nane independently. I do think it's likely that Nick Bruty just made a mistake though.
